# How can we separate nested tag into single individual tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

There is a requirement to break the below "p" tag into two separate "p" tag. The complete piece of html is the below html

```
<div>
<h2> Making Things Possible </h2>
<p><em><br> by David</em>, Year 2012</p>
</div>
```

I want to make the above html in the below format

```
<div>
<h2> Making Things Possible </h2>
<p><em><br> by David</em></p>
<p>Year 2012</p>
</div>
```

Need help... I have tried to do it by the below piece of code

```
Elements byline = elements.select("p");
            if (!byline.isEmpty()&& elements.select("p").first().text().contains("by") ) {
                if (byline.select("p em").first().text().contains("by")) {
                    Element firstH2heading = elements.select("h2").first();
                    if (firstH2heading!=null) {
                        firstH2heading.after("<p><em>"+byline.select("p em").first().text()+"<em><p>");

                    }
                    byline.select("p em").first().remove();
                }

            }
```

Is there any batter way to do it....

Comment: It is very nice for this requirement to exist. Also what do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear... I have edited the question..

Comment: the context is missing here. One solution would be this: ```String newStr = "<p><em><br> by David</em>, Year 2012</p>".replace(", ","</p>/n<p>")```, but I somehow doubt that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @luksch I have changed the question again. The final output i want is <div>
<p><em><br> by David</em></p>
<p>Year 2012</p>
</div>

Comment: With context I did not mean the surrounding divs, but why you need to solve this, and do you need to solve it only in this very special case. The problem is that people do not understand how general your solution must be. It there a pattern to be recognized? Is the comma a good indicator as I think? All that is not clear from your question. Also, it is good practice to show some own effort. Describe what you have tried so far and where it fails. Include stack traces if you get an error... look here: https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042856-asking-a-question

Comment: Got it @luksch. My question is very simple there is a paragraph tag <p><em><br> by David</em>, Year 2012</p> . But task is to split the paragraph tag into two. After splitting what will be the output I have shown in my question.